# Changing flutter dart code not changing the ui on 'flutter run' on ios or android emulator

Tags: flutter, macos, apple-m1

I just created a flutter project in my new m1 mac. I ran flutter doctor- all boxes are checked. But when I changed something in my code, I see no changes in IOS and Android emulators. It's showing the ui that Flutter creates automatically on creating a new project. Even if I delete all ui codes, it's still showing no changes. I am so puzzled now. Someone, please help me understand why is it happening and what is the cure.(Update:: Using android studio instead of vs code,  all are okay!!)
Thank you.

Comment: close your question then

Comment: @Rationalist I still need to know the reason. Using vscode is much easier than using android studio. It would be great if I can solve the problem, and resume working in vscode

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is solved. What happened is that the 'Auto save' was checked as off in my vscode editor.

What I did>>

- Go to settings.
- Search 'Auto Save'.
- Change it from 'Off' to 'afterDelay' / 'OnFocusChange'.

Now all are okay. Hot reload or restart are working just fine. Thank you.